# Cannot boot elementary OS from external drive from OS X

Tags: system-installation, boot

Installation of elementary OS was successful but when I attempt to boot into elementary OS that drive doesn't show up with the other bootable drives. I can see the drive in Disk Utility but I cannot mount it.

Answer (score 1):

You should install a bootloader that supports running other OSs than Apple made. My fav is [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/). When you're done, you can select any OS from any drive connected to your Mac (I assume you don't hackintosh).